# Unbounded synaptic weight in Hebb’s rule

Tags: neuroscience, brain

I am new to neuroscience and apologies in advance if this is a very trivial question. I want to model the synaptic weights of neurons and using the discrete Hebb’s update rule

$$w_{n+1}=w_n(1+c)$$

That is whenever two neurons fire in succession the synaptic weight is increased by a factor c. But here the synaptic weights are unbounded and grow to infinity. Is there any other simple discrete update rule which takes care of this. I came across Oja’s rule but it seems to depend on postsynaptic and presynaptic activity

Comment: Are you looking for a rule based on a biological mechanism, or simply one suitable for simulating biologically-motivated network activity? Oja's rule certainly seems like it would be an answer, but it's not clear to me why you suggest it depends on "postsynaptic and presynaptic activity", or why that would be a *problem*, per se.

Comment: Actually, in my model there are only two states of the neuron. Either it fires or it doesn't.  So I don't have a measure of the post or presynaptic activity. Do you think I can use Ojas rule in this setting?

Comment: My understanding is the only difference between Oja and Hebb is Oja scales the weight vector to have length 1.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oja%27s_rule perhaps as a start? Or go right to the source: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00275687.pdf